# Can a wind turbine full-scale converter absorb active power?

Tags: power-electronics, converter

Is a full-scale converter of a wind turbine type 4 capable of absorbing active power? If it is possible, where would this power be dissipated?

If yes, where would this active power go, in the capacitor of the converter?

Comment: I think you might need to add some words to make it less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no practical reason for a wind turbine power generation system to absorb active power from the grid. The converter could conceivably be configured to receive the power and drive the generator as a motor, but there is not a reason to do that. There is no way to dissipate active power except to operate the turbine as a huge fan.

I have seen "type 4" wind generation system defined as a system with a full-scale converter (all generated power is converted). It can use a wound field synchronous generator (WFSG), permanent magnet synchronous generator (PMSG), or squirrel cage induction generator (SCIG). The design can include the supply of reactive power from the grid through the converter for machine excitation. If a WFSG is used, it can be used to supply/absorb additional reactive power through the converter.

There is power required for the "balance of system (BOS)" components. BOS would include electronic control equipment, motors for positioning the turbine and adjusting the blade angle, and even electric heaters to protect the equipment from low temperature and condensation when it is out of service. Power for the BOS would be supplied from the grid directly, not through the converter.